# VBA_String cannot be added into array(Error: Expected array)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I'd like to add a long string, such as "OA_OB_OC_OD_n1" into an array. Then use the function Split to seperate it into several parts and put them into my sheet, like:
OA|OB|OC|OD|n1|

Here is my code (all the Dim have been done):

Public Sub Boutton_Importer_Click()

```
list_de_controle = "TEXT;" & listPath
Open listPath For Input As #1  
'to read a list which contains the name of files I want to open

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich  'read the name of file
    WrdArray() = Split(nom_de_Fich, "_")  'here is the problem

    For Each wrd In WrdArray()
        ActiveCell.Value = wrd
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next wrd

    Open nom_de_Fich For Input As #2  'open the file
    Insérer_contenu  'I have a function here to read the contents
    Close #2

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
Loop
Close #1
```

End Sub

If I change this part:

```
Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich  'read the name of file
WrdArray() = Split(nom_de_Fich, "_")  'here is the problem

For Each wrd In WrdArray()
    ActiveCell.Value = wrd
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next wrd
```

into:

```
Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich  'read the name of file
ActiveCell.Value = nom_de_Fich
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

That works well. So i don't know how to fix that.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Although I typically will not write the `()` while using the array (only on dimensioning)  I wrote a quick test case and it does not fail using your syntax.

Comment: Sorry for this delay. The error is expected array. I think that means the array is still empty?

Comment: I've written a smaller one, in the following Comment. If you may, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a smaller one, it's more simple to read:

```
Sub try()

    Dim longstr As String
    Dim myarray() As String
    Dim wrd As Variant

    longstr = "OA_OB_OC_OD_OE_OF_OG"


    myarray() = Split(longstr, "_")
    For Each wrd In myarray
        ActiveCell.Value = wrd
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Should this snippet also throw the "expected array" error? Just ran it in Excel 2013 and worked fine...

Comment: I've delete everything and write again, and it works... I'm confused but it works at last. Thank you after all!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe I've done nothing just delete all and write everything again and it works.
Thank you after all! Have a good day!